# How to check for presence of a directory in Inno Setup preprocessor?

Tags: preprocessor, inno-setup

What I am trying to do is:

```
#define SAMPLE_DOCS_ROOT "C:\SampleDocuments\"
#if CLIENT != ""
  #define SAMPLE_DOCS_CLIENT SAMPLE_DOCS_ROOT + "client\" + CLIENT
  #ifexist SAMPLE_DOCS_CLIENT
    #define SAMPLE_DOCS_PATH SAMPLE_DOCS_CLIENT + "\*"
  #endif
#endif
```

SAMPLE_DOCS_PATH never gets defined even though there is SAMPLE_DOCS_CLIENT folder.

It seems that the `#ifexist` ISPP directive does not accept absolute nor relative directory path, and only accepts file paths. Is there a way to check for the presence of a directory at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`DirExists`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_direxists.htm) function. The [`#ifexist`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_ifdef.htm) directive can be used only for files. So write this instead:

```
#define SAMPLE_DOCS_ROOT "C:\SampleDocuments\"
#if CLIENT != ""
  #define SAMPLE_DOCS_CLIENT SAMPLE_DOCS_ROOT + "client\" + CLIENT
  #if DirExists(SAMPLE_DOCS_CLIENT)
    #define SAMPLE_DOCS_PATH SAMPLE_DOCS_CLIENT + "\*"
  #endif
#endif
```

Comment: How to use DirExists at compile time. Can you give an example, please?

Comment: I've added an example... Don't be confused, there are two `DirExists` functions; one for runtime and one for preprocessor.